# Make the hash value unique in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

For example I am having the hash

```
 var sample={};
 sample["test"] = [];
 sample["test"].push({name: "test"});
 sample["test"].push({name: "test"});
```

The sample hash should only contain unique values.

Comment: What you mean by `sample hash`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique values in javascript hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976128/unique-values-in-javascript-hash)

Comment: The values in the sample should only contain unique records

Comment: in the sample {} or []?

Comment: So is `sample == { "test": ["boo", "hoo"], "other": ["hoo"] }` valid or not?

Comment: Ulas Hunka I have already tried tried but its is not working for me

Comment: Do you mean unique keys in the object {} ? or unique values in the array [] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes i got the solution for that

```
var sample = [{ id : 1, name : 'Name' }, { id : 1, name : 'Name' }];
var obj = { id : 1, name : 'Name' };
var sample = [obj, obj];
uniq(sample)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hej man it isn’t possible to got another hash value from 2 same value’s.
For simplify a hash operation is likely like plus so you got 1 + 2 = 3.
It is not that easy but I hope you got he point.